# Почему тело цикла называется именно телом?

Tags: циклы, терминология

Собственно, интересен ответ на вопрос, почему сложилось такое название. Гуглить пытался, но ничего не смог найти.

Comment: Меня тоже с детства интересует вопрос - почему стул называется именно стулом.

Comment: Вряд ли тут есть объяснение интереснее "давным давно кто-то назвал именно так, вот и прижилось". Не факт даже, что этот кто-то до сих пор жив и/или может об этом что-либо сказать. Альтернативных наименований мне неизвестно, так что возможно и говорить о том, что "название сложилось" не имеет смысла – из чего оно сложилось, из единственного варианта?

Comment: В HTML тоже есть тег `body`. Это всё связано с тем, что человек любит романтику. Он и "нейронные сети" так назвал, хотя это тоже имя нарицательное. Тело - ибо это бо'льшая часть цикла, которая находится именно в середине цикла

Comment: Ну если бы `зад` назывался бы `телом`, а `тело`,   `задом`, то `тело цикла` назывался `задом цикла`....  Я так думаю...

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос больше относится к анатомии, не же ли к программированию....

Comment: Наверное, потому что "тело" есть не только у цикла, но и у функции, у оператора ветвление и других конструкций. Еще есть интересный вариант. Что *внутри* цикла? Его "внутренности") А где находятся внутренности? В теле! :)

Comment: @Igor, потому что он плоский, располагается выше земли и не является столом....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если посмотреть определение слова «тело» в [обычном словаре](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/240254), то можно увидеть в том числе такое:

> Основная часть, корпус чего-н. (спец.). Т. орудия (ствол). Т. мины. Т. поршня. Т. плотины (её основная часть). Вегетативное т. гриба (грибница). Рудное т. (скопление руды). Т. дерева (ствол).

Вполне очевидно, что в этот ряд вписывается и «тело цикла».